# Reflection Exception error caused while using a extension in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am using `faryshta/yii2-disable-submit-buttons` extension for disabling submit buttons when submitting a form in yii2.

I installed the extension using composer and I entered  `'faryshta\assets\ActiveFormDisableSubmitButonsAsset'`, in `$depends` property in `AppAsset` file which is required.

But there is error as:

> ReflectionException Class
>   faryshta\assets\ActiveFormDisableSubmitButonsAsset does not exist

Comment: Are you sure you installed the extension correctly? Are the files in your `vendor` folder?

Comment: Yes, they are in vendor folder

Comment: Have you escaped the slashes? It should be `'faryshta\\assets\\ActiveFormDisableSubmitButonsAsset'`